# Insert into SQLite file Python - does not work

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a simple database application in Python with SQLite. I wrote a simple program to create database and insert into some values. However, database is created, but new values are not inserted, and I don't know why:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys


def CreateTable():
    try:

        connection = lite.connect(':memory:')

        with connection:

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authors' + '(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT)'
            cursor.execute(sql)

            data = '\n'.join(connection.iterdump())
            with open('authors.sql', 'w') as f:
                f.write(data)

    except lite.Error, e:
        if connection:
            connection.rollback()
    finally:
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

def Insert(firstname, lastname, email) :
    try:

        connection = lite.connect('authors.sql')

        with connection:

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT INTO Authors VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s)" % (firstname, lastname, email)
            cursor.execute(sql)

            data = '\n'.join(connection.iterdump())
            with open('authors.sql', 'w') as f:
                f.write(data)

    except lite.Error, e:
        if connection:
            connection.rollback()
    finally:
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()



CreateTable()
Insert('Tibby', 'Molko', 'tibby.molko@yahoo.co.uk')
```

Comment: Why do you have two different database connections? One is in-memory, the other a file.

Comment: because I need to append some values into already created database. Is that possible?

Comment: Then just open a connection to *that database*. SQLite database files are not like text files, you don't append to them. Leave it to SQLite to manage the data in the file.

Comment: So how can it be done? I don't really get the idea. My problem is that I write a quite bigger app, where I need to create the database at some point, and then let users add (insert) some values into it, so it will be stored in previously created database

Comment: Just *connect to the existing database*. You already wrote your table creation such that it only creates the table if not already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood what `connection.iterdump()` is *for*. You are creating **SQL text**, instructions for SQLite to execute again at a later date. It is not the *database itself*. If all you wanted was to output SQL statements you can just write your SQL statements directly, there is little point in passing it through SQLite first.

You also cannot 'connect' SQLite to the text file with SQL statements; you'd have to load those statements as text and re-play them all. That's not what I think you wanted however.

You can connect to an existing database to insert additional rows. Each time you want to have add data, *just connect*:

```
def CreateTable():
    connection = lite.connect('authors.db')

    try:
        with connection as:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = '''\
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authors (
                    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    FIRSTNAME TEXT,
                    LASTNAME TEXT,
                    EMAIL TEXT)
            '''
            cursor.execute(sql)

    finally:
        connection.close()


def Insert(firstname, lastname, email) :
    connection = lite.connect('authors.db')

    try:
        with connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT INTO Authors VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (firstname, lastname, email))

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Note that using the connection as a context manager already ensures that the transaction is either committed or rolled back, depending on there being an exception.

On the whole, you want to be informed of exceptions here; if you cannot connect to the database you'd want to know about it. I simplified the connection handling as such. Closing a connection auto-closes any remaining cursors.

Last but far from least, I switched your insertion to using *SQL parameters*. Never use string interpolation where parameters can be used instead. Using parameters makes it possible for the database to cache statement parse results and most of all prevents SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. The only thing I can add to your answer is that you need to write `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` instead of `ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` to be able to write `INSERT INTO Authors VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling commit on your connection. You should also not write to the database file yourself, the database engine is writing to the file.

Try to go through the first few examples in [sqlite documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html), it should be clear then.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to a text file with sql commands.
`sqlite3.connect` expects or creates a binary file.

Comment: Where does the OP use a text file to insert?

Comment: so how can i append some values into existing sqlite database?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, the in-memory database is handled very weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt `commit` it.For `writing` into database, it should be committed.For read (select) operations,not needed.

```
try:
    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO Authors VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (firstname, lastname, email))
        connection.commit() # or cursor.commit()


finally:
    connection.close()
```